# Map commas to # in an HTML form

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code here:

```
var name = $('#name01').val();
var description = $('#description').val();
var option1 = $('#Option1').val();
var option2 = $('#Option2').val();
var data = [name, description, option1, option2].join(",");
google.script.run.saveDataAsCSV(data, uploadParentFolderId);
```

Its function is basically to return the values ​​of the `HTML` form to the `.gs` file of my script, thus making it possible to generate a `.csv` file with these values.

The issue is that I would like any comma that is typed in this form to be replaced by `#` before generating the `.csv` file.

For that, I tried to modify the code like this here:

```
var name = $('#name01').val();
var description = $('#description').val();
var option1 = $('#Option1').val();
var option2 = $('#Option2').val();
var form_values = [name, description, option1, option2];
form_values = form_values.map(r => r.map(c => c.replaceAll(",", "#")));
var data = form_values.join(",");
google.script.run.saveDataAsCSV(data, uploadParentFolderId);
```

However, with this modification, the form stops working, opening a blank screen when it is submitted.

How to adjust it?

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have too many calls to `map()`. `r` is a string, not an array, you can't map it.

```
form_values = form_values.map(r => r.replaceAll(",", "#"));
```

Comment: Wow, that's exactly it! Sorry for the extremely basic question, I'm a beginner but trying my best. Thank you very much for your help and attention!